# If i import SmsManager from my own project It does not works and then the Project is terminated

Tags: android

I copied `android.telephony.SmsManager` in my project and tried to send SMS using functions from that class , If import SmsManager from my own project then the Project is terminated but    if I `import android.telephony.SmsManager` then the project is working perfectly.

Comment: First and foremost, you need to include the error message or logcat messages that you get when you ask questions about a crashing application. Second, why would you need to copy `SmsManager` into your project?

Comment: I want to make some changes in the SmsManager. java file so I copied it into my project. NO error is there but if I run the project in my phone then the message appear "Unfortunately the project is teminated"